# Cancelling Token doesn't throw OperationCanceledException in Android .Net MAUI

Tags: .net-6.0, .net-maui

I am trying to download a file and allow the user to cancel the download process. I am downloading it in another thread and doing UI changes as well. While canceling the process I don't get `OperationCanceledException` in Android while the same code works file in iOS.

**MVVM Section**

```
[RelayCommand]
    void DownloadFile(ReciterChapterDownload reciterChapterDownload)
    {
        if (ReciterChapterDownloads.Any(x => x.DownloadReciterChapterId == reciterChapterDownload.DownloadReciterChapterId) && !reciterChapterDownload.Downloaded)
        {
            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                reciterChapterDownload.Downloading = true;
                reciterChapterDownload.CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

                var progressIndicator = new Progress<double>(reciterChapterDownload.ReportProgress);
                var response = await _fileDownloadService
                    .DownloadFileAsync(reciterChapterDownload.DownloadLink, reciterChapterDownload.GetDestinationDownloadPath(),
                    progressIndicator, reciterChapterDownload.CancellationTokenSource);

                switch (response?.FileDownloadStatus)
                {
                    case FileDownloadStatus.Completed:
                        reciterChapterDownload.Downloading = false;
                        reciterChapterDownload.Downloaded = true;
                        break;
                    case FileDownloadStatus.Cancelled:
                        reciterChapterDownload.Downloading = false;
                        break;
                    case FileDownloadStatus.Failed:
                        reciterChapterDownload.Downloading = false;
                        await App.CurrentShell.DisplayAlert("Operation Failed", response.StatusMessage, "OK");
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**MVVM Cancel Download**

```
[RelayCommand]
        void CancelFileDownload(ReciterChapterDownload reciterChapterDownload)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!reciterChapterDownload.CancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    reciterChapterDownload.CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"CancelFileDownloadCommand {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
```

**Download File Async Cancel section**

```
using (cancellationTokenSource)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

                        using (var fileStream = FileDownloadService.OpenStream(tempFilePath))
                        {
                            using var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(token);
                            var totalRead = 0L;
                            var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                            var isMoreDataToRead = true;

                            do
                            {
                                // cancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // this line also didn't help
                                if (cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                                {
                                    await fileStream.FlushAsync();
                                    fileStream.Close();
                                    await fileStream.DisposeAsync();

                                    return new()
                                    {
                                        StatusMessage = $"Download Operation Cancelled",
                                        FileDownloadStatus = FileDownloadStatus.Cancelled
                                    };
                                }

                                int read = 0;

                                if ((read = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, token)) > 0)
                                {
                                    await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer.AsMemory(0, read), token);

                                    totalRead += read;

                                    if (canSendProgress)
                                    {
                                        progress.Report((totalRead * 1d) / (totalData * 1d) * 100);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    isMoreDataToRead = false;
                                }

                            } while (isMoreDataToRead);

                            await fileStream.FlushAsync(token);

                            fileStream.Close();

                            await fileStream.DisposeAsync();
                        }

                        File.Copy(tempFilePath, destinationPath, true);

                        FileAccessHelper.DeleteFile(tempFilePath);

                        return new()
                        {
                            StatusMessage = "Operation Completed Successfully",
                            FileDownloadStatus = FileDownloadStatus.Completed
                        };
                    }
                    catch (OperationCanceledException)
                    {
                        return new()
                        {
                            StatusMessage = $"Download Operation Cancelled",
                            FileDownloadStatus = FileDownloadStatus.Cancelled
                        };
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        // Logger.LogException(e, properties);
                        const long ERROR_HANDLE_DISK_FULL = 0x27;
                        const long ERROR_DISK_FULL = 0x70;
                        long errorCode = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHRForException(e) & 0xFFFF;
                        if (errorCode == ERROR_HANDLE_DISK_FULL || errorCode == ERROR_DISK_FULL) {
                            return new()
                            {
                                StatusMessage = $"Operation Failed, Disk Fill",
                                FileDownloadStatus = FileDownloadStatus.DiskFull
                            };
                        }

                        return new()
                        {
                            StatusMessage = e.Message,
                            FileDownloadStatus = FileDownloadStatus.Failed
                        };
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
                    }
                }
```

In android, it never goes to `OperationCanceledException`, but goes to the `Exception` section and throws this exception.

```
Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException: Exception of type 'Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException' was thrown.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue using

```
await Task.Run(async () => {});
```

instead of

```
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {});
```

Comment: For cross-platform reliability, get back to MainThread before making UI changes. Now that you have moved to a separate thread via `Task.Run`, maybe wrap `switch (response?.FileDownloadStatus) ...` inside `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`.

Comment: That's a great idea. I was throwing error in case of failures and was catching them outside Task.Run(()=). Now all set inside MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread. Thank you.